# How do I create an exit animation where multiple views perform different animations as they exit?

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin, material-design

I am having difficulty figuring out how to animate multiple views in an exit transition.

Here's the scenario I currently have:

You have a login screen with an ImageView at the top and two EditTexts at the bottom.  When both EditTexts are filled in, a login FAB will appear.

Here is what I'm trying to do from here:

When the login FAB is clicked, all the steps below should be performed simultaneously:

1. The ImageView does a slide_out_top animation
2. The EditTexts (which are inside a single LinearLayout) does a slide_out_bottom
3. The FAB stays where it is, but transforms from a green FAB with an arrow icon to a blue FAB with a plus icon

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out the example in this github project : https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations I combined animation for 2 views at stat up. I guess in similar way you can do it at the time of exit. When all the animation finishes call the finish() method

Comment: So can I use scenes to create transitions use different animations across multiple views in an activity?